# Multiple .zip files extracting on the app directory c#

Tags: zip

I have an auto update program for game launcher and I want to know how I can auto unzip all zip files on the same folder with launcher. (Multiple zip files are downloaded). I am a newbie when it comes to coding.

I need to change the following code for extracting all .zip files in the current folder where the app is.

```
using (var zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read("desktop.zip"))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### @vendettamit is give me the correct answer. If someone need im going to post his code.

```
 foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("<directory path>", "*.zip")) 
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry zipFiles in zip)
        {
            zipFiles.Extract(currentpath, true); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Reflection:

```
 using (var zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read("desktop.zip"))
        {
            string exeFullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string exePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFullPath);

            zip.ExtractAll(exePath
                          , ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
```

Comment: i have multiple zip files on directory how it can be help to extract all zip files in same directory? Also file names re not specific.